# How to add OnItemClickListener on a Listview in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

My Main activity class is this.. I have the position of the list items just I want is to know how to add browser activity against every list item. So that when an item in the list is clicked it navigate to that web site. If Google in the list is Clicked it should navigate to google.com

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Main extends ListActivity {



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);        
        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,R.id.textView1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries)));

        }


        private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        int textViewResourceId, String[] strings) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView tv =  (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        tv.setText(items[position]);


        if(items[position].equals("Pakistan")){

            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.apk);

            }

        else if(items[position].equals("Canada")){

            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.canada);
            }

        else if(items[position].equals("India")){

            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.india);
            }

        else if(items[position].equals("UAE")){

            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.uae);
            }
        return row;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I am having problem in posting my code, help?

Comment: copy the relevant code and post it here. What help do you need regarding. DO read the site FAQ once

Comment: Sorry mate, I am new here that's why having problems.. I have posted the code.. have a look on it please for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its a ListActivity. Override `onListItemClick`

```
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id)

Added in API level 1
This method will be called when an item in the list is selected. Subclasses should override. Subclasses can call getListView().getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to access the data associated with the selected item.

Parameters
l   The ListView where the click happened
v   The view that was clicked within the ListView
position    The position of the view in the list
id  The row id of the item that was clicked
```

Since you have ImageView in your layout it may take focus when you click on List item.

So add this `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the root element in `list_item.xml`

Comment: @SikanderEjaz in your activity override `onListItemClick`. If you are using eclipse. Right click Source Override Implemented methods Look for onListItemClick

Comment: @SikanderEjaz and add this `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` for the root element in `list_item.xml`

Comment: Its saying "Vote Up requires minimum 15 reputations" and I have only got 1, because I have joined today.

Answer (score 0):

This code work for your case, in on item click, go to particular url, you want

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {


            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });
```